# How to update JSON array into list object in angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I modify JSON object with new object in angularjs controller . I have given the two json format. I need to modify JSON with new JSON object.

Input is coming from form submission

```
{
  "motivationForFinDifficulty": "sds",
  "motivationForConcession": "sddsd",
  "motivationForModificationOrRefin": "dsasa",
  "administrationVO": {
    "measureCode": {
      "0": "C",
      "1": "B"
    },
    "measureType": {
      "0": "Refinancing",
      "1": "Temporary"
    },
    "measureDescription": {
      "0": "ok",
      "1": "ok"
    }
  }
}



<pre>

I want this below output .



{
  "motivationForFinDifficulty": "sds",
  "motivationForConcession": "sddsd",
  "motivationForModificationOrRefin": "dsasa",
  "administrationVO": [{
    "measureCode": "C",
    "measureType": "Refinancing",
    "measureDescription": "ok"
  }
  {
    "measureCode": "B",
    "measureType": "Temporary",
    "measureDescription": "ok"
  }
]

}
```

Comment: Why don't modify form submission?

Comment: What have you tried already? This is not supposed to be a free code-writing service :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new object from existing one

```js
var x = {
  "motivationForFinDifficulty": "sds",
  "motivationForConcession": "sddsd",
  "motivationForModificationOrRefin": "dsasa",
  "administrationVO": {
    "measureCode": {
      "0": "C",
      "1": "B"
    },
    "measureType": {
      "0": "Refinancing",
      "1": "Temporary"
    },
    "measureDescription": {
      "0": "ok",
      "1": "ok"
    }
  }
}

// getting getAdministrationVO 
var getAdministrationVO = x.administrationVO;
// an empty array for pushing objects
var administrationVO = [];
// get all the keys from the administrationVO
var keysLength = Object.keys(getAdministrationVO);
// considering all keys(object) of administrationVO have same number of keys
var subKeys = Object.keys(getAdministrationVO.measureCode);
// loop through it and add value from each of the nested object
for (var i = 0; i < subKeys.length; i++) {

  var m = {};
  m.measureCode = getAdministrationVO.measureCode[subKeys[i]];
  m.measureType = getAdministrationVO.measureType[subKeys[i]];
  m.measureDescription = getAdministrationVO.measureDescription[subKeys[i]];
  // push the object in array
  administrationVO.push(m)
}
// create new object using predefined value and newly created array of object of administrationVO 
var newObj = {
  "motivationForFinDifficulty": "sds",
  "motivationForConcession": "sddsd",
  "motivationForModificationOrRefin": "dsasa",
  "administrationVO": administrationVO
};
console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response.